# Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream

Tags: java, json, mule

I am getting following error while reading the json data from text file. I am using transormer as *json to object*. I gave return class as `java.util.HashMap`. I tried to insert the data read from text file i.e. is in json format.

After running the application I got the below error.

```
Failed to transform from "json" to "java.util.HashMap". 
   Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException). 
   Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream.
```

How to send data from text file to DB?

Comment: Please update your question with the Mule XML code and an example of your file.

Comment: Unable to help you out without clear question, please explain in detail and mule config xml.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `object-to-string` after file inbound and then try to use `json-to-object`. Looks like json to object is not able to decode from input stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can add transformer in the File Connector itself. In the File Connector, go to transformers and add json-to-object there.